# Split string Dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table as below:

```
Column1   Column2        Column3
-----------------------------------
A         NULL           NULL
A]B       NULL           NULL
A]B]C     NULL           NULL
```

There can be millions of records like these and I need a SQL query to obtain output as below

```
Column1  Column2    Column3
-----------------------------
A        NULL       NULL
A        B          NULL
A        B          C
```

Comment: Do not over-trivialize your sample data. A table has a fixed number of columns and there must be a fixed upper limit in any solution. Have you done your analysis and identified this limit? Don't assume. Splitting strings is a common topic and it will serve you well to learn from past discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query:

```
    --test data
    declare @tbl table (Col1 varchar(10), Col2 varchar(10), Col3 varchar(10));
    insert into @tbl values
    ('a',null,null),
    ('a]b',null,null),
    ('a]b]c',null,null);


    select case when firstIdx = 0 then col1 else substring(col1, 1, firstIdx - 1) end Col1,
           case when firstIdx = 0 
             then null 
             else case when secondIdx = 0 
               then substring(col1, firstIdx + 1, 100)
               else substring(col1, firstIdx + 1, secondIdx - firstIdx - 1) 
             end
           end Col2,
           case when secondIdx = 0 
             then null
             else substring(col1, secondIdx + 1, 100) 
           end Col3
    from (
        select Col1,
              charindex(']', Col1) firstIdx,
              charindex(']', Col1, charindex(']', Col1) + 1) secondIdx
        from @tbl
    ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

2 step process it is 
a)you need to create a function as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split]
(
    @string varchar(MAX),
    @delimiter CHAR(1),
    @pos INT 
)
RETURNS varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT, @count INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string), @count = 1 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN
        IF @end = 0 
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1 

        IF @count = @pos
            RETURN SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)

        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
        SET @count = @count + 1 

    END 
    RETURN '' -- not found
END
```

b)getting the value of all the for all 3 columns like this

```
select isnull(dbo.split(cloumn1, ',', 0),'') as Column1,isnull(dbo.split(cloumn1, ',', 1),'') as Column2, isnull(dbo.split(cloumn1, ',', 2),'') as Column3 from <Table_Name>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can handle this using multiple comma separated CTE.

Below query has two CTE table `t0` and `t1`. Table t0 pulls the position of the first `']'` using `charindex` function and similarly, `t1` is used to pull the position of the next `']'`.

Using the `case statement` and `substring` function you can get the desired output.

```
with t0 as ( select Column1, Column2 ,  Column3, charindex(']',Column1) pos from #tbl),
     t1 as (select  Column1, Column2 ,  Column3, charindex(']',Column1,t0.pos+1) pos from t0)
select case when t0.pos = 0 then t0.column1 else substring(t0.Column1,0, t0.pos )  end Column1,
       case when t0.pos = 0 then null else substring(t0.Column1,t0.pos+1,case when t1.pos= 0 then len(t0.Column1)+1 else len(t0.Column1)- t1.pos end)end Column2,
       case when (t0.pos = 0 or(t0.pos <>0 and t1.pos =0)) then null else substring(t0.Column1,t1.pos+1, len(t0.Column1)+1 )   end Column3 
from t0
inner join t1 on t0.Column1 = t1.Column1
```

**output**

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
------- ------- -------
A       NULL    NULL
A       B       NULL
A       B       C
```